# MYSQL select join multiple table and SUM

Tags: mysql, join, sum, left-join, inner-join

I have three tables

1.master

```
id_master barcode name last_stock 
1         123     abc  15 
2         234     bcd  10 
3         345     cde  7 
4         456     def  11 
5         567     efg  20
```

2. trans_in

```
id_trans_in barcode qty time_trans 
1           567     1   2016-04-01 10:15:09
2           234     2   2016-04-01 14:15:09
3           345     5   2016-04-01 20:15:09
```

3. trans_out

```
id_trans_out barcode qty time_trans 
1           123     3   2016-04-01 09:15:09
2           234     5   2016-04-01 08:15:09
```

I must build a query to give result

```
id_master barcode name last_stock in out
1         123     abc  15         0   3
2         234     bcd  10         2   5
3         345     cde  7          5   0
4         456     def  11         0   0
5         567     efg  20         1   0
```

I just trying simple query

```
select
    a.id_master, a.barcode, a.name,
    COALESCE(SUM(b.qty),'0')
from
    master a
inner join trans_in b
on a.barcode = b.barcode
where
    date(b.time_trans) = '2016-04-01'   
group by a.barcode
```

the result is

```
id_master barcode name COALESCE(SUM(b.qty),'0')
5         567     efg  1
2         234     bcd  2
3         345     cde  5
```

i dont know how to combine full list of master, trans_in and trans_out by time_trans (if null then 0), i already try using left join, inner join on three of them but the result make me dizzy.. result from SUM more than qty from field, i really dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can left join to some derived tables just in case you get multiple entries per date

```
    SELECT  a.id_master ,
        a.barcode ,
        a.name ,
        a.last_stock ,
        COALESCE(b.`IN`, 0) AS `IN`,
        COALESCE(c.`OUT`, 0) AS `OUT`
FROM    master a
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT barcode, SUM(qty) as `IN` 
                     FROM trans_in 
                     WHERE date(time_trans) = '2016-04-01' 
                     GROUP BY barcode ) b ON a.barcode = b.barcode
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT barcode, SUM(qty) as `OUT`
                     FROM trans_out 
                     WHERE date(time_trans) = '2016-04-01' 
                     GROUP BY barcode ) c  ON a.barcode = c.barcode;
```

Comment: getting error syntax, i put single quote in every as ('in', 'out'), remove comma after as out, but still getting error syntax in different line "unknown b.barcode in on clause..

Comment: dang.. sorry.. need to include barcode in your derived tables.. i'll update

Comment: work like a charm bro... really smooth query... thanks again my bro.. :D

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT m.* 
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'trans_in' THEN qty END),0) `in`
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'trans_out' THEN qty END),0) `out` 
  FROM master m 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT 'trans_in' type
            , id_trans_in id_trans
            , barcode
            , qty
            , time_trans 
         FROM trans_in 
        WHERE time_trans BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-01 23:23:59' 
        UNION ALL
       SELECT 'trans_out'
            , id_trans_out
            , barcode
            , qty,time_trans 
         FROM trans_out
        WHERE time_trans BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-01 23:23:59' 
     ) x 
    ON x.barcode = m.barcode
 GROUP 
    BY m.id_master
 ORDER
    BY id_master;
```

Consider storing transactions in a single table. It will simplify and accelerate this process. Also, I've assumed an INDEX on time_trans, and built a range query accordingly.